# Using foreach and split together

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach, split

i'm having a problem with a split inside a foreach in javascript

```
var res = data.split(",");
                    res.forEach(function(entry) {
                        var fields = res.split("|");
                        var div = fields[0];
                        var val = fields[1];
                        $("#" + div).html(val);
                    });
```

can anyone help me understand why this is not working?

matt

Comment: What error it gives to you?

Comment: This is [Javascript, not Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java). Specifically, you appear to be using [jQuery](https://blog.udemy.com/jquery-vs-javascript/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `res.split("|");` it should be `entry.split("|");`

```js
var data = "v1|1,v2|2,v3|3"

var res = data.split(",");
res.forEach(function(entry) {
  var fields = entry.split("|"); //here
  var div = fields[0];
  var val = fields[1];
  $("#" + div).html(val);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="v1"></div>
<div id="v2"></div>
<div id="v3"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a for loop

```js
var res = data.split(",");
for(var each in res){
  var fields = res[each].split("|");
  var div = fields[0];
  var val = fields[1];
  $("#" + div).html(val);
}
```